# useState not updating in parent after initial call from child

Tags: react-hooks, react-props, react-state-management

I have a parent/child relationship, but the parent's state is not getting updated after the initial call from the child.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [carouselIndex, setCarouselIndex] = useState(0);
  const [translateValue, setTranslateValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChangeHero = () => {
    console.log("I'm in the parent component"); // This line gets called successfully every time it's invoked from the child, so the child and parent seem to be communicating.
    setCarouselIndex(carouselIndex + 1); // carouselIndex gets updated correctly on the first call (going from 0 to 1), but on every subsequent call from the child, this line gets ignored.
    setTranslateValue(translateValue + -(slideWidth())); // Same problem with this line: gets called on the first invocation only, then gets ignored on subsequent calls.
  }

  return (
    <Child changeHero={handleChangeHero} />
  )
}

const Child = props => {
  const bind = useGesture( // from "react-with-gesture".
   ({
    args: [index],
    down,
    delta: [xDelta],
    distance,
    direction: [xDir],
    velocity,
  }) => {
    if (!down && (xDelta < -150 || xDelta > 150)) {
      handleChangeHero(); // Method gets called here, when the user releases the mouse click
      gone.add(index);
    };
  },
);
  const handleChangeHero = () => {
    console.log("I'm in the child component"); // This line is called successfully every time this handler is invoked in the child. It's part of a method from "react-with-gesture".
    props.changeHero();
  };
 return (<div>I'm a child</div>);
}
```

How do I get `setCarouselIndex` to get called every time?

Comment: Can you show the code where you invoke the `handleChangeHero` function of child component?

Comment: Updated.  This code is based off of https://github.com/GavBaros/react-tinder-cards.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a solution using react-redux.  I can keep track of the carousel index value in the redux action function, and combine it with `document.body.clientWidth` in the parent to calculate the `translate-x` value.  For some really weird reason, the state in the parent would not update from the child (prior to the return statement in the child), even though the event handler was being called.